# Copy data from one child node into another Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android application where there are two types of user. I differentiate them into the system by using the field UserType. I have a requirement where I have to copy data from one child node into another. I am using Firebase for my backend. I have gone through other answers but this requirement is unique in a way that, I want to copy data only on a particular node. Attaching the Firebase database structure

[image: Firebase Database Structure]

In this structure, if you can see I have expanded 2 child nodes of "users". One of the child has userType as Standard User and other child has userType as Guardian User.

1) I want to copy the "fullNameGuardian" child alone from the user with key starting with "L4bTr6q" to the user with key starting with "dC9Mq" 
2) I want to copy the "standardEmail" child alone from the user with key starting with "dC9Mq" to user with key starting with "L4bTr6q".

And everytime I add a new user, the user can be with one of the userType "Standard User" or "Guardian User". So is there a possibility like I do it for every new user?

I am having difficulties figuring out how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you know those ids? L4bTr6q... and dC9Mq...? Are those ids stored into variables? What should happen when you need to copy this?

Comment: @AlexMamo - I am not gonna change any values of the fields I get. In the profile screen, for example for standard user, I just to set the name and email of the guardian and viceversa.

Comment: Ok, but do you know L4bTr6q... and dC9Mq...? Can you use them?

Comment: @AlexMamo - No I can't see them! I am not able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could save the other structure when you save the first one. For instance,

```
Save   - node1/child
Update - node2/child
//and so on
```

Another way is using Firebase functions(Real database triggers) in order to automatically do something after something else had happened. Check it out.

Comment: The problem is, I use the same form to get the details of both users.